# How to echo html text with specified tabs

Tags: php, html, regex, tabs, xampp

I'm trying to echo html text with tabs. The tabs at the beginning of each line should equal the number of tab units I want for the text block, and that is determined by the tabbing of the surrounding tags (`<div>`, etc.) I'm also stripping out unnecessary white space characters in the text that I'm displaying, but retaining CR/LF. I've written the following PHP function to do this; it takes the text to be displayed and the number of tab characters to be employed as arguments, strips out unnecessary white space characters with regex, and attempts to replace each end-of-line character with PHP_EOL plus the tab indent for the following line:

```
function html_source_view_echo($display_text, $tab_indent) {

    // Clean-up white spaces and replace any line break in the text with a
    // newline + the tab_indent
    $html_source_view_text = preg_replace('/\v(?:[\v\h]+)/', PHP_EOL . $tab_indent, $display_text);

    // Start with the initial tab_indent, then follow it with the edited text 
    // (so that the edited text is prefixed by the same tab indent
    // desired for the HTML output...all for the sake of readability):
    echo $tab_indent . $html_source_view_text . PHP_EOL;

}
```

My PHP/HTML code therefore looks like this for a `<section>` whose content should be indented 4 tab units (because `<section>` is indented 3 tab units, and I want its content indented one additional tab than it is indented):

```
            <section>
<?php
$tab_indent = "\t\t\t\t";
html_source_view_echo($display_text, $tab_indent);
?>
            </section>
```

On my XAMPP localhost, it formats it correctly, indenting the text by the number of tabs specified, like this:

```
    <section>
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        <p>etc.</p>
    </section>
```

On my live host, it fails to apply the tabs, and the resulting HTML is output this way:

```
            <section>
<h2>Info</h2>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>etc.</p>
            </section>
```

I've tried replacing PHP_EOL with "\n", etc., but that seems to make no difference; the function only works on my local host (XAMPP). Any clues why this is failing to work on the live host? (Perhaps there's a PHP configuration directive I need to enable on the live host, etc.)

Comment: Different `PHP` versions [which might not support `\v`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) ? It is only supported as of `5.2.4` (which dates back to 2007, admittedly...).

Comment: @Jan, that's not the issue...the regex handles the `\v` correctly. I'm using PHP 7.03 on my localhost and 7.02 on my live server. The issue is that it's not inserting the tab `\t` characters when run on the live server. Any clue?